# How to customise jquery ui dialog box title color and font size?

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript

How can I change color and other attributes of the jquery ui dialog box title

```
HTML :
<div id="dialog" title=""
style="display: none; font-size: 15px; width: 500; height: 300"></div>

javascript :
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "title",title );
```

Please give me some idea to customize the title of jquery dialog.Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These classes shape the container of the dialog box title

```
ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix
```

This class shapes the text

```
ui-dialog-title
```

You could edit these classes in the css file for the jquery ui style. Or you could overwrite these in your own css file.

```
.ui-dialog-title{
    font-size: 110% !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background: #000000 !important;
}
```

The "!important" might not be necessary.

You can find this out yourselves using developer tools.

Comment: thank you it was useful. but title to be changed as header in class name.

Comment: .ui-widget-header 
       { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; 
         background: #cccccc url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png) 
         50% 50%    repeat-x;   color: brown;    font-size: medium; 
       }